# Apache2 : How to remove port from URL?

Tags: apache2

I have the following Apache configuration file for a reverse proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443> 
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/NewPC-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/NewPC-access.log common
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2    
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/localhost.key
</VirtualHost>
```

The reverse proxy works properly but I always have the port number (5000) in the URL.

Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? where is this port 5000? is it in the main URL or the upstream URL?

Comment: @ManishDash the reverse proxy should redirect requests from internet to an internal local application accessible from localhost:5000. The internal application is correctly exposed to internet but the url has always the port shown : like example.com:5000

Comment: @ThomasCarlton, yes you are right. I am also confused why this happened to you. Try clearing browser cache once.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks good and what you described shouldn't happen unless it's the application running behind the proxyPass that is sending a redirect/location to the client including the port.
You can test it simulating requests to the application running on port 5000 with curl (-v option) or the tool you prefer.